# how can update Cordova application from a server?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I am building a jQuery mobile application and will wrap it with Cordova. I almost finish it and right now I want to know how can I update my application remotely.

Since my application is build by JQM, so my code is actually a website (js/css/html files). I want to know how can I remotely replace those files while there is a new version. For example:

I write some new code into app.js file. And I put it into a a server like update.com/app/app.js.

Now I want my application to be able to visit **update.com/app/app.js** , and download new app.js and replace the one in local. And then restart the application. a update process finished.

**PS: I don't want to download whole new .apk file to reinstall application. I just need to be able to update my asserts remotely.**

Thanks

Comment: you can try this plugin https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-contentsync

Comment: A few more links: - [Microsoft CodePush](https://microsoft.github.io/code-push/),
- [ionic Deploy](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/deploy-overview),
- https://github.com/markmarijnissen/cordova-app-loader